# Is there a way to tell the user-agent "treat this tag like that one"?

Tags: html, css

I want `<foo>` tags to act *exactly equivalent* to `<bar>` tags, without knowing anything about the styles applied by the site's stylesheet, user's stylesheet, or the default user agent behavior. For example, making a `<bq>` tag which acts exactly like a `<blockquote>` tag or a `<latinname>` tag that should inherit from the `<em>` tag's styles.

In other words, is there a way to tell `foo` to inherit *everything* from `bar`'s style?

Comment: Oops, I accidentally some words :)

Comment: As a side note, you can't make up your own HTML elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must, use the [CSSOM](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/) and iterate through every selector of every rule of every stylesheet (`document.styleSheets`), replacing `foo` with `bar` where appropriate. I'd recommend you use CSS classes instead.

Answer (score 2):

CSS inheritance is on a property by property basis. So unless you explicitly state to inherit via the property, the default value will be used.

Another approach is to set up classes which can live across tags. Keep in mind that the tags should be the structure, not the style.